# Change Size (Width and Height) of Graph (GraphViz & dot)

Tags: graph, graphviz, dot

Often, the default layout of graphs drawn by GraphViz in the dot language is a little "tight." With too little visual space, it's hard to put meaningful labels on edges and the graph can look cluttered.

How do I affect the vertical and horizontal spacing of GraphViz / dot graphs?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### DEFAULT

I will start with a simple graph that is laid out by the dot engine in the default manner:

```
digraph {
node [shape=circle, width=0.4];
A->B
A->D
B->C
D->E 
}
```

[image]

### CHANGING HEIGHT

As you can see, the layout is quite tight.  Notice that my ranks (rows) naturally go from top to bottom.  I can affect the **height** of the graph by exploiting this and using the `ranksep` (rank separation) variable to explicitly set the space between the ranks:

```
digraph { 
node [shape=circle, width=0.4];
ranksep = 1;
A->B
A->D
B->C
D->E 
}
```

[image]

### CHANGING WIDTH

Finally, we may want to widen the diagram.  Here we use the `nodesep` variable to increase the space between the nodes (columns):

```
digraph { 
node [shape=circle, width=0.4];
nodesep=1.5;
A->B
A->D
B->C
D->E 
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any official documentation available? Thanks.

Comment: @jabellcu Of course, it's at http://graphviz.org  It's much-changed since I answered this question four years ago, but looks better now.

Comment: If you're using `dot` command to visualize a generated digraph, you can add these as options to the command: `-Granksep=1` or `-Gnodesep=1.5` etc.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ratio argument as well as specify within the documentation
https://graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html