# How do I change the width & height of a graphviz SVG

Tags: svg, graphviz, jquery-svg

My output SVG graph using Graphviz is stretched out more horizontally.
How do I make it expand more vertically?
Or is there a way to increase the length of the edges?

Comment: Please see my previous answer on this exact topic [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44735236/change-size-width-and-height-of-graph-graphviz-dot).  Please remember to accept and upvote.

Comment: @JLH Seems like that answer is for DOT file. I need something for SVG format

Comment: Hi @JLH Thanks for the answer. But I am really looking how to modify my SVG file itself so that the nodes are more spaced apart vertically. Here is my SVG file : https://gist.github.com/abhijitdhar/1ed86355a0180f8666d2f7fe3f9a6eb3

Comment: See the "changing height" section [of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44735236/change-size-width-and-height-of-graph-graphviz-dot).

Comment: Yes,  I saw the ranksep answer. But where should I put that attribute? It tried putting it both in <g> and <svg> elements. But it has no effect.

Comment: Hi @JLH I pasted my raw SVG here - https://gist.github.com/abhijitdhar/1ed86355a0180f8666d2f7fe3f9a6eb3?short_path=aca2160

Answer (score 1):

I had the same requirement. To specify the SVG output size use [size](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/size/) attribute at the Graph level. (Units are inches, with '!' the drawing is scaled up uniformly until at least one dimension matches the size)

```
digraph "Custom Size Graph" {
    graph [size="11,8.5!"]; 
    Root -> A;
    Root -> B;
    Root -> C;
    A -> D;
    A -> E;
    B -> F;
    C -> G;
    C -> H;
}
```