# How to show lots of nodes in GraphViz clearly?

Tags: graph, data-visualization, graphviz

I use GraphViz to draw graphs and analyse links between our business objects.
Here is an example of source code:

```
digraph G {rankdir=LR;
    "6012013856_0010" -> "6012014462_0010"
    "6012013856_0010" -> "6012014471_0010"
    /* ~1000 more id1 -> id2 pairs */
    "6012013856_0010"
    "6012013859_0010"
    /* ~300 more single ids */
}
```

Pastebin examples: [large graph - 1300 LoC](https://pastebin.com/Ks5wrP43) , [smaller graph - 240 LoC](https://pastebin.com/jqbii5eP)

Looking at my graph its impossible to understand what nodes are connected with each other.
I looking for any GraphViz options to show clearly all my edges in this case.

Comment: Your example has >1300 lines of code. Please create [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Issue only occurs on big data. I simplified source code to minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Please see [my other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44735236/change-size-width-and-height-of-graph-graphviz-dot/44735237#44735237) describing how to spread out your nodes.

Answer (score 1):

While "large graph" is not that big, it is quite interconnected and difficult to visualize.  Post-processing the **dot** output with **GVPR** to move the highly-connected nodes helped a bit (sorry, too big to post), but **circo** gave a better result (to my eye) (again, too big to post).
note 1: **SVG** output was much more "zoomable"
note 2: **circo** took about 5 minutes to run on my computer